# Array filling in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to fill 1 as an element of array `FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray` starting with  index 500 in new array, and 0 for other index. Done like the following but the new array is getting filled only by 0. Explanation : at index 600,800,1200,1300 element in `FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray` should be 1 and 0 in all other indexes including for index 2(because 2 is less than 500)

```js
var j = 500;
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = new Array();
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
  if (FilteredRPeakDataArray[j] == i) {
    FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[i] = 1;
  } else {
    FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[i] = 0;
  }
  
  j++;
}

console.log("FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray " + FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray);
```

Comment: you don't have the position `500` on `FilteredRPeakDataArray`, so, just compare `j==i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had two problems

one is that you were advancing J index anyway

and the main one was  this line : `FilteredRPeakDataArray[j] == i`

FilteredRPeakDataArray was an array with only 5 elements and you were going with huge indices.
there is better ways to implement what you trying to do but I guess you are new to js (or maybe coding) so this fix will give you a better understanding of what went wrong

```
var startFrom = 500;
var j=0;
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = new Array();
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2,600,800,1200,1300];
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = new Array();

        for (var i=0;i<1500;i++){
      if(FilteredRPeakDataArray[j]==i){
if( i > startFrom ){
        FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[i] = 1;
}
        j++;
      }
      else{
        FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[i] = 0;
      }


     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Array.from().

```js
const FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];

const FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = Array.from({length: 1500},
 (_, i) => FilteredRPeakDataArray.includes(i) && i > 500 ? 1 : 0
);
console.log(FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

first fill all the elements of array with `0` 's and later change the required indexes to `1`

```js
var j = 500;
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = new Array();
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = new Array(1500).fill(0);

for (var i = 0; i < FilteredRPeakDataArray.length; i++) {
    
  FilteredRPeakDataArray[i]>=j ? FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[FilteredRPeakDataArray[i]]=1:null
  

}

console.log("FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray " + FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with `0` for all 1500 indexes using [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill). Thne loop through `FilteredRPeakDataArray` and update only those indexes which have value > `j`

```js
var j = 500;
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = Array(1500).fill(0);

FilteredRPeakDataArray.forEach(n => {
  if(n > j)
    FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[n] = 1;
})

console.log(FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[2]);
console.log(FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[600]);
console.log(FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[800]);
```

Comment: it should be `n >= j` instead of `n > j`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const start = 500;
const limit = 1500;
const FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];
// fill array with 1s
const FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = new Array(limit).fill(1);
// change value of indices stored in FilteredRPeakDataArray to 0
for (const idx of FilteredRPeakDataArray) {
   if (idx >= start) {
      FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[idx] = 0;
   }
}
console.log("FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray " + FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just pre-fill the array with 0 and then set 1 for those specific indexes:

```
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = new Array(1500);
FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray.fill(0);
for (const index of FilteredRPeakDataArray) {
    if (index >= j) {
        FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[index] = 1;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var j = 500;
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = new Array(1500);
FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray.fill(0);
for (const index of FilteredRPeakDataArray) {
    if (index >= j) {
        FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[index] = 1;
    }
}

// Show results
for (const index of [0, ...FilteredRPeakDataArray]) {
    console.log(`FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[${index}] = ${FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[index]}`);
}
```

But if you want to set those values as you build the array, you can use `Array.from`'s callback:

```
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = Array.from({length: 1500}, (_, index) => {
    return index >= j && FilteredRPeakDataArray.includes(index) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var j = 500;
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = Array.from({length: 1500}, (_, index) => {
    return index >= j && FilteredRPeakDataArray.includes(index) ? 1 : 0;
});

// Show results
for (const index of [0, ...FilteredRPeakDataArray]) {
    console.log(`FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[${index}] = ${FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[index]}`);
}
```

---

[`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) are both relatively recent additions to JavaScript, but both can be polyfilled easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `j` with `i` and then check for particular value inside `FilteredRPeakDataArray` array

```js
var j = 500;
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = new Array();
var FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];
var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = new Array(1500).fill(0);

for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
  if (i >= j && FilteredRPeakDataArray.includes(i)) {
    FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[i] = 1;
  } else {
    FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[i] = 0;
  }
}

console.log( FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fill the 1500 element array with 0's from the start, filter the array to those element greater than j, and replace all indices with 1's:

```js
var j = 500;

var FilteredRPeakDataArray = [2, 600, 800, 1200, 1300];

var FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray = new Array(1500).fill(0);

FilteredRPeakDataArray.filter(el => el > j).map(el => FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray[el] = 1)

console.log("FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray " + FilteredRPeakThousandDataArray);
```